# List in php expandible

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that you add as a list, I want only 3 elements to be shown and make the rest appear by clicking on the * show more * button.

```
$printstring .= '<ol>';
foreach ($rows as $bid) {
    $printstring .= '<li>';
   if ($bid->bidder_url != "" && $customcontact = "") {
      $printstring .= '<a href="'.$bid->bidder_url.'" rel="nofollow">'.$bid->bidder_name.'</a>';
   } else {
      $printstring .= $bid->bidder_name;
   }
   $printstring .= ' bid '.$currencysymbol.number_format($bid->current_bid_price, 2, '.', ',').' on '.get_date_from_gmt($bid->date);
   //if ($bid->bid_type == "auto") $printstring .= ' [auto]';
   $printstring .= '</li>';
 }
 $printstring .= '</ol>';
```

I found that it can be done with js but I don't see how to join both (php and js).

```
 $(function() { 
var numToShow = 3;
var moreLi;
$('ul').children('li').hide().each(function() {
    if ($(this).index() < numToShow) {
        $(this).show();
    }
}).parent('ul').append('<li><a href="#" id="showMore">More</a></li>');

$('#showMore').click(function() {
    moreLi = $(this).parent('li');
    moreLi.siblings().show();
    moreLi.remove();
});
});
```

Comment: You’re not going to “join” php and javascript.  In fact, if you are careful to separate logic from presentation in your script, it becomes much clearer and easier to work with. If you think of your script as two separate sections, php and view, only using php in the view for iteration and variable insertion— you can clearly see what the browser receives, which makes writing the javascript much easier.  That being said, your question becomes only a javascript question.

Comment: For the javascript, I would make a class or data attribute for each row that would act as a hook for your javascript to use to show or hide elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that PHP works in backend (in the webserver) and JS works in frontend (in your web browser). Basically, JS should send a request (you could learn about sending requests with Ajax) to PHP, and PHP should return a response to be printed by JS.

If you are new in this kind of scenario, it might be confusing at first. I encourage you to learn about how to send a request with Javascript and parse the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `for($i = 0;$i......` then when `$i= 4` `echo 'Show more...';break;`

It should work

Comment: sorry i cant understand how i can do